# Dynamically assigning anonymous generic functions in pascal

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, anonymous-function

I have the following class hierarchy

[image: Class]

I would like to be able to dynamically assign anonymous methods which operate on objects of both types `TB` and `TC`.

So here is a simple contrived example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TNotifyEventWrapper = class
    private
      FProc: TProc<TObject>;
    public
      constructor Create(Proc: TProc<TObject>);
    published
      procedure Event(Sender: TObject);
    end;

  IA = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TA = class(TInterfacedObject)
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TB = class(TA, IA)
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TC = class(TA, IA)
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TControl = class
    strict private
    public
    class var NEW : TNotifyEventWrapper;
    class var Foo : TNotifyEvent;
    class function GetWrapper<T:TA, IA, constructor>(D: T): TNotifyEventWrapper;
    class procedure AssignFooHandler<T:TA, IA, constructor>;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TC.Foo;
begin
    ShowMessage('TC.Foo');
end;

class function TControl.GetWrapper<T>(D: T): TNotifyEventWrapper;
begin
    Result :=
    TNotifyEventWrapper.Create
    (
        procedure (S : TObject)
        begin
            T(D).Foo;
        end
    );
end;

class procedure TControl.AssignFooHandler<T>;
var
    X : T;
begin
    X := T.Create;
    try
        TControl.NEW := TControl.GetWrapper<T>(X);

        TControl.Foo := TControl.NEW.Event;

    finally
        FreeAndNil(X);
    end;
end;

procedure TA.Foo;
begin
    ShowMessage('TA.Foo');
end;

procedure TB.Foo;
begin
    ShowMessage('TB.Foo');
end;

constructor TNotifyEventWrapper.Create(Proc: TProc<TObject>);
begin
    inherited Create;
    FProc := Proc;
end;

procedure TNotifyEventWrapper.Event(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FProc(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TControl.Foo(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TControl.AssignFooHandler<TC>;  //TB
end;

end.
```

I would like to be able to call

`TControl.AssignFooHandler<TC>;`

And have the `TControl.Foo(Sender);` method invoke `TC.Foo`

Also I want `TControl.AssignFooHandler<TB>;` to result in `TControl.Foo(Sender);` invoking `TB.Foo`

Unfortunately, when I run this, it always invokes the base class method `TA.Foo`.

[image: MessageBox]

I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: I also tried Creating another class `TD = class(TA, IA)` and using that as the generic parent. This did not produce any different results.

Comment: I just found that renaming `TA.Foo` to `TA.FooBar` is one way of fixing the problem. I think this is because delphi replaces base class methods before interface methods.

Comment: Are you sure that TControl is a good choice of name?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Now that you point that out, its probably not the best choice considering its already the name of a class in VCL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Generic is constrained to descendants of `TA` and `IA`.  `TA.Foo` is not declared as `virtual`, and `T(B|C).Foo()` are not declared to `override` it.  That is why `TA.Foo()` is being called every time.  You need to make `TA.Foo()` virtual and `T(B|C).Foo` override it, then `T(B/C).Foo` will get called as expected.

Also, you are freeing the `T(A/B/C)` object that you are passing to `TControl.GetWrapper()` before `TControl.Foo()` ever gets a chance to invoke the `Foo()` method of that object.  In this particular example, it is OK since none of the `Foo()` methods access any object member fields, but once you start doing that in actual production code, it is likely to crash.  You need to keep the `T(A/B/C)` object alive until you are done using the `TNotifyEventWrapper` object.